# What happened to "unsafeSubscribe()" operator in RxJava2?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

There's no mention of it in https://rxjava-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/What%27s-different-in-2.0/ and I can't see it among suggestions while coding. I can see "safeSubscribe()" though.

Was it removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v1, the default `Observable.subscribe` method added a safety wrapper over the incoming `Subscriber` (called `SafeSubscriber`) to protect against some misuse or other unconventional behavior (such as crashing `onError` and `onCompleted`).

This was generally penalizing to operators thus the `unsafeSubscribe` was introduced and employed by most operators.

V2 became much stricter about `Observer` behavior as the Reactive Streams specification forbids crashing the `onNext`, `onError` and `onComplete` methods. In the hopes that people won't explicitly crash in these methods when implementing `Observer` or they simply used the lambda-`subscribe()` methods instead, the default safety wrapping has been removed. So the base assumption became that `Observer`s will behave nicely. Therefore, the `unsafeSubscribe` method was no longer needed. Also being an API refresh opportunity (binary compatibility is not mandated between major version jumps), we had the option to remove or rename old methods for various reasons.

Unfortunately, some implementors still were unreliable in this regard and expected the old safety net. To avoid hurting the well-players, the `safeSubscribe` method was introduced that guards against such misbehavior as gracefully as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment 

I got your point and understandable. Maybe it should be mentioned in the wiki so that it's clear why it was removed. I was following "Intro To Rx" Github resource which is still in RxJava1 and in order to showcase use of serialize() operator, it was using unsafeSubscribe() to prove a point. What would you say about this? Serialize can be still useful for some situations?

Comment: I don't think many people (other than operator writers) knew about `unsafeSubscribe`. I've updated the [wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#instance-methods) table about the methods. Serialize -> I don't think it is useful anymore and it will be probably removed in 3.x. It had some value with early operator writers who violated the serialization requirement of the Observable protocol. Nowadays, most people know writing custom operators is the last resort and having such late serialization is often not enough. But that's a different discussion.

Comment: Good to know about this small update on future direction of RxJava. Thanks once again for your time.